# UWP CanvasRenderTarget giving corrupt image

Tags: uwp, win2d

I'm doing a "hello world" type test with win2d. 
In my canvas draw event, this gives me a nice round circle as I expect:

```
args.DrawingSession.FillCircle(100, 100, 50, Windows.UI.Colors.Red)
```

But I would like to draw "off screen", so I tried this:

```
    Dim dev As CanvasDevice = sender.Device
    Dim crt As New CanvasRenderTarget(dev, CSng(sender.ActualWidth), CSng(sender.ActualHeight), sender.Dpi)
    Dim ds As CanvasDrawingSession = crt.CreateDrawingSession
    ds.FillCircle(100, 100, 50, Windows.UI.Colors.Red)

    args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(crt)
```

This sort of works but as I resize the page to force redraws, I see all sorts of strange corrupted images, looks like tearing, uninitialsed memory, etc.

What is going on and how do I fix this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, need to do ds.flush before DrawImage to get the hardware renderer to actually do it

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call CanvasDrawingSession.Flush in rare cases involving interop between different graphics APIs.  This will sorta work for what you are doing here, but is far more expensive than necessary.

The problem is that you are not disposing your drawing session.  The return value from CreateDrawingSession needs to be disposed when you have finished drawing to it.  In C# that is typically done via a "using" statement, although explicitly calling Dispose has the same effect.  Afraid I don't know VB well enough to advise what the VB equivalent of "using" is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out, need to do ds.clear at the start and ds.flush before DrawImage to get the hardware renderer to actually do it